# I am getting an error of "Image file is missing or invalid" while uploading a product via form-data with postman

Tags: node.js, postman, mern

[The Form Data and the error below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QLSV8.png)
I saved the image data in my local storage. However I am getting an error:
"Image file is missing or invalid".

Here is my controller code:

```
exports.create = (req, res) => {
  let form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
  form.keepExtensions = true;
  form.parse(req, async (err, fields, files) => {
    if (err) {
      return res.status(400).json({
        error: "Image could not be uploaded",
      });
    }
    let product = new Product(fields);

    // use same name as model and file name type

    if (files.photo && files.photo.path && files.photo.type) {
      const filePath = path.normalize(files.photo.path);
      const fileType = mime.getType(files.photo.type);
      product.photo.data = fs.readFileSync(filePath);
      product.photo.contentType = fileType;
    } else {
      // handle error
      return res.status(400).json({
        error: "Image file is missing or invalid",
      });
    }
    // continue with other code
    try {
      const result = await product.save();
      res.json(result);
    } catch (err) {
      return res.status(400).json({
        error: errorHandler(err),
      });
    }
  });
};
'''

I d
```

Answer (score 0):

This could happen if the file was not properly uploaded in the form or if there was an issue with the formidable package.

Check the request payload in the browser console or using Postman to ensure that the image file is being properly uploaded with the request.

You can also check if you're inserting images in the right place in postman.

If you're still having trouble, you could try using a different package for handling file uploads, such as multer. Here's an example of how you could modify your controller code to use multer instead of formidable:

Make sure to require the necessary modules at the top of your file:

```
const multer = require("multer");
const fs = require("fs");
```

Make sure to attach the upload middleware to your route:

````
 const storage = multer.diskStorage({
   destination: (req, file, cb) => {
     cb(null, "./uploads/");
   },
   filename: (req, file, cb) => {
     cb(null, new Date().toISOString() + file.originalname);
   },
 });
 
 const fileFilter = (req, file, cb) => {
   if (file.mimetype === "image/jpeg" || file.mimetype === "image/png") {
     cb(null, true);
   } else {
     cb(new Error("Invalid file type"), false);
   }
 };

const upload = multer({ storage: storage, fileFilter: fileFilter });

exports.create = async (req, res) => {
try {
 const product = new Product(req.body);

 if (!req.file) {
   return res.status(400).json({ error: "Image file is missing or invalid" });
 }

 product.photo.data = fs.readFileSync(req.file.path);
 product.photo.contentType = req.file.mimetype;

 await product.save();

 return res.json(product);
} catch (err) {
 return res.status(400).json({
   error: errorHandler(err),
 });
}
};```

Hope this was helpful !
````

Comment: I checked via postman's console and I have the image data as undefined. I will try using another package

Comment: I'm still getting the error.